# converting 32 byte array buffer to hexadecimal character in C

Tags: c

I have 32 byte char buffer when printed in hexadecimal using function

```
void print_buffer_in_hex(const char* buffer, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

it is shown as below

```
5ca6d40011278e3ff84fd94dd80e370cd90f2a304e9cefb946082ab82ff0dbde
```

how can I convert above data to string of 64 bytes (i.e., character array of 64 byte buffer) instead of printing to console.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Do you know about `sprintf`?

Comment: Please decide "convert array to string" (as in the title) or "convert string to ... character array of 64 bytes" (as in the body). I perceive that as opposite things. Maybe just rephrase to avoid my misunderstanding.

Comment: It ain't hard to code this yourself without sprintf. `LUT[somebyte & 0xF] + 256 * LUT[somebyte >> 4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment mentioned, you can use `sprintf(3)`, which writes the usual printf-formatted output to a buffer:

```
char buf[65] = {0}; 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sprintf(buf + i*2, "%02x", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
}
buf[64] = 0;
```

The `i*2` stands for the offset of the buffer you want to write to.

Answer (score 0):

The question says the source is 32 bytes long and the destination buffer is 64 bytes long, so I assume that no null terminator character is to be appended to the destination (since that would require the destination buffer to be at least 65 bytes long).

The following function converts each byte in the source buffer to two hex digit characters in the destination buffer, which is assumed to be at least twice as long as the source.  It does not append a null terminator character to the destination buffer contents.

```
/* Assume destination buffer is at least `2 * source_size` bytes long. */
size_t hex_encode(char *destination, const char *source, size_t source_size)
{
    static const char hex[16] = "0123456789abcdef";
    size_t d_ix = 0;
    size_t s_ix;

    for (s_ix = 0; s_ix < source_size; s_ix++)
    {
        unsigned char byte = source[s_ix];
        destination[d_ix++] = hex[(byte >>> 4) & 15];
        destination[d_ix++] = hex[byte & 15];
    }
    return d_ix;
}
```